How to find which labeled rows from a table are at or above certain points from another table using Python?
I'm new to Python and am struggling to understand how to code this specific situation. I have included an Excel screenshot to better describe the tables and graphs I am working with. From Table 1, column headings 10-13 serve as the x-values. Row # Label provides which row between 1-6 is being affected. Table 2 provides 2 points: A and B. How can we determine which of the 1-6 rows intersect or are above point A? What about for point B?
Logically, I know point A should be at or below all 6 rows and B should be at or below rows 4 and 6. Python should print {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} when asked about A and print {4, 6} when asked about B.
However, how do we translate this process to be done in Python where there are two tables set up just like these?
Table 1 and Table 2
I have tried something like this, but it not working and I think it would only output the total number of rows like 6 for point A and 2 for point B instead of the specific Row # Label that I am looking for as well.
# Iterate through the points in Table #1
for i in range(len(table_one)):
    x = table_one[i][0]
    y = table_one[i][1]

# Iterate through the matrices in Table #2
for j in range(len(table_two)):
    m = table_two[j]
# Calculate the x and y values of the matrix
    m_x = np.sum(m, axis=0) * [i]
    m_y = np.sum(m, axis=1) * [i]

# Compare the x and y values of the point with those of the matrix
if np.any((np.abs(x - m_x) <= 0.5) & (np.abs(y - m_y) <= 0.5)):

# Increment the counter variable
    intersection_count = intersection_count + 1


You need to correct the indentation in your code.

Oops! Thanks for pointing that out, but I do know it's a more in-depth issue than just that. lol!

When working with tables in Python, I suggest that you use pandas. It is typically imported like this import pandas as pd.
Let us consider the following example tables:
data1= {'11': [0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 2, 0.6, 1.2], '12': [0.3, 0.33, 0.18, 2.5, 1, 1.4]}
data2= {'Point': ["A","B"], 'X': [11,12], 'Y': [0.18, 1.24]}
table1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
table2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)

table1 is similar to the left-hand side table in your snapshot, table2 is the one is the right-hand side.
If I understand your question correctly, for a given abscissa (X) in table1  you want to check which samples are above the ordinate (Y) in table2.
Let's consider:
abscissa = 11

Then your threshold is:
threshold = table2[table2.X==abscissa]['Y'].to_numpy()

The corresponding column name in the first table is X = str(abscissa).
To check which values in the corresponding pandas series are greater or equal than the threshold you can do the following:
table1[X].ge(threshold[0])

Of course, this returns "True" for all rows.
If you repeat the same using abscissa = 12, this will return:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
Name: 12, dtype: bool


EDIT: to answer your additional question in the comment section, pandas cannot handle columns sharing the same name. For instance, if you try importing a csv file containing multiple columns named 11, pandas will rename them to 11, 11.1, 11.2, etc... That being said you could easily extract the abscissa from these column labels:
for column in table1.columns:
    abscissa = int(float(column))
    threshold = table2[table2.X==abscissa]['Y'].to_numpy()
    table1[column].ge(threshold[0])

Then it is just a matter of concatenating the different series to form the table that you are after.

Thank you so much! You were very clear with your explanation and this has helped me better understand how Python handles this process. Thanks again!

I came up with another question. How would the code change if table 2 had repeating X values such as X: [11, 11, 11, 12] with Y: [0.18, 0.1, 0.2, 1.24]. How would we get it to print a table displaying true or false for each of the three 11s and then the one 12? What I have now is only registering the first 11 and the first 0.18. I'm struggling to get it to loop through the remainder of the Y values.

I edited my answer to address your new question.
